# Finite State Machine language

Tags: discrete-mathematics

for the following language, how can i find the regular expression and how do i define a finite state machine that recognizes words in the language (input alphabet, states, start state, state transition table, and accept states). and finally how do i make a state digraph for the FSM

L: For alphabet {x,y,z}, all strings that contain xyx or zyz.

Comment: This same question has been asked in the past 24 hours about 5 times.  The only change has been the example to work.  Check out the other posts.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression for the language is as follows: $(x + y + z)^{*}(xyx + zyz)^{+}(x + y + z)^{*}$.

We pick any elements in the alphabet as many times as we want. Then we get at least one of $xyx$ or $zyz$, and then we pad at the end with elements from the alphabet as desired. I will leave the FSM to you to start.